# How can I get featured image for a post in October CMS via Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, blogs, octobercms

I'm using RainLab.Blog plugin for my blog. Also I'm trying to create a subscription script for my site and successfully managed to get both `title` and `slug` parameters from the database,use them whenever I want to send latest posts via mail. Everything works fine, but I also want to send featured image, which can be added to the post, while it's being created : [image: img]

Is there a way to include it in the following script, considering that I've already extracted both title and slug parameters from `rainlab_blog_posts` table. And obviously there are no links to featured images in this table :

```
foreach($blogPosts as $posts) 
{
$text .= '<a href="https://somesite.com/blog/post/'.$posts->slug.'">'.$posts->title.'</a><br>'; 
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check Post Model to find relation between posts and images

if method name is **featured_images** so you can get images with `$posts->featured_images`

But I guess **featured_images** is not one to one relation and each post could have more than one image

so you should decide which images you want to get to display

in your sample code:

```
foreach($blogPosts as $posts) 
{
$text .= '<a href="https://somesite.com/blog/post/'.$posts->slug.'">'.$posts->title.'</a><br>';

$image .= $posts->featured_images[0]->path; 
}
```

featured_images[0] get first image in featured_images and also path is the column name that store path of featured image to add this path in img src

also

`$posts->featured_images->first()->path` is another way to get an image of post